Is it a good idea to immerse the circuit in an engineered fluid in order to minimize circuit drift
I'm designing an extremely high precision current source. I'd like it's long term drift to be no higher than 1 ppm. This circuit consists of a high stability voltage reference (e.g., LM399), a 20-bit DAC, ultra-low drift op-amps, precision resistors, and so on.
To achieve the accuracy I need, I need to eliminate as much as possible the drift due to temperature drift, temperature gradients, stresses. I came up with the idea that I could soak my board with an engineered fluid (for example, Novec 8200) and then keep that fluid at a constant temperature with a heating circuit, thus ensuring that the entire circuit is at a uniform constant temperature. The engineered fluid is vacuumed to eliminate oxygen and moisture.
I consulted some of my engineer friends and they don't think it's a good idea because the chips/resistors I'm using could deteriorate chemically in the engineering liquid, a process whose duration could be years. Some thought that a chip like the LM399 might fail due to excessive heat dissipation from the liquid.
They haven't been able to convince me, but it seems difficult to refute their points. Has anyone done anything similar? Is this idea a genius idea, a conditional genius, or always stupid?

I'm guessing it's low power and so the amount of heat is small, and so perhaps you don't need a high thermally conductive liquid and perhaps a gas or solid would do.  Heated air?  Or mount everything on a lump of copper.  Aluminium PCB, heated?  The choice and management of the liquid seems to add a very large complication.  Water-"coolers" like used for CPUs, with maintained temperature?

You should use a "polysulfone" container for the LM399 heated to 50 Celsius ( or a little more) ...

First of all, the reference, op-amps, and resistors all generate a significant amount of heat, and this heat will change significantly with the current configuration, so there is no way to ensure a constant temperature without using a high thermal conductivity medium.
I considered solids, but I haven't found a suitable material that would do the job, resins (filled with thermally conductive material) create a lot of stress when curing, creating stress-induced drift, and silicone actually has a very low thermal conductivity, which I suspect won't establish a good enough constant temperature

You’ll need to insulate the ovenized reference, if you use the internal heater and you should take the datasheet numbers seriously when they talk about typical long-term drift, as Andy mentions. There's also hysteresis that will come into play if you ever lose power (or control authority) and the reference returns to room temperature or otherwise departs from the controlled temperature. Transfer references can have chunky backup batteries for this reason.
You might be able to get close to the desired performance with an array of LTZ1000 ovenized buried zeners, with some conditioning (burning in- perhaps a month or two), selection of 'good' units, and assuming they don't tend to all drift in the same direction (a point for research, I simply don't know if this is true or not). If they drift randomly you could get a \$\sqrt{N}\$ improvement with N references, and the LTZ1000, which is pretty much within striking distance.

It's well known that the packaging and stresses thereof can affect the precision, so the good old TO-5 package with some care to mounting and PCB sculpting is probably the best choice.
While immersing the circuit in some liquid would probably improve the sub-1Hz 1/f noise, liquids have a way of getting contaminated with ions and becoming conductive over time, even if they don't inherently attack any component of the circuit.
I have done something somewhat similar, however the time scale of 'long term' drift was limited by the amount of fuel the vehicle containing the instrument could carry, and was more like single-digit hours than months.


I'm designing an extremely high precision current source, and I'd like it's long term drift to be no higher than 1 ppm.

The LM399 has a specified long term drift of typically 8 ppm /\$\sqrt{kH}\$: -

So, in 1000 hours (42 days) the drift is typically 8 ppm and way more than the requirement you state above. I believe you need to rethink your requirements. You appear to be ignoring the elephant in the room.

"H" is Henry, "h" is hour. Given the electrical context, I legitimately though you meant kilohenries until I checked the image. I'd suggest the edit directly, but it's too short.

Vaelus I'm unsure what response you expect

I am suggesting changing "8 ppm / $\sqrt{kH}$" to "8 ppm / $\sqrt{kh}$".

The 1ppm goal is probably too hard, but I'd like to set a hard goal and then see how far I get. On the subject of the LM399, I don't think you can simply look at the performance in the manual, the LM399 is a widely used reference and it's pretty cheap, on the one hand I can get some dismantled LM399's that have been aged for years or even decades, and then after some filtering, close to 1 ppm performance has been reported. But in any case, the thermostat requirement is always the same

I guess you should make a custom topography thermal block from aluminum or copper, which bonds all your PCB components together, fill the voids between components with insulating TIM. The only thing that you need to isolate (maybe with some plastic or foam around it) is the ovenized reference.
Finally seal the entire unit, and throw it into a thermalized oil bath, which you temperature regulate using a large metal thermometer (e.g. many Pt resistors).
Note this will minimize thermal drift/noise but cannot rule out aging, so you will need to recalibrate the setup routinely, especially during the first couple of 1000 hrs.
Also note that integrated DACs typically have quite a bit of 1/f noise. So it will be hard to keep their noise below 1 ppm. It might be better (i.e. much easier) to modulate the whole application with some kHz frequency. If you insist on DC, it could be necessary to build your own DAC, which for 1 ppm probably means making a careful delta-sigma DAC with differential flip-flops and copious post filtering.

Novec 8200 is a solvent, and might attack plastics used in component packaging. A silicone oil or a transformer oil would probably be a better choice.

Will transformer oil or silicone oil ensure that it doesn't affect most of the circuit components?  I chose the Novec 8200 simply because I know people who soak their servers in it to dissipate heat.

If people soak servers in Novec 8200 then either it doesn't attack circuit components, or they are damaging their servers. Hopefully the former. I wasn't aware of that practice. Silicone oil is quite inert. Transformer oil is at least inert to the enamel coating used on transformer wires.

@RaymondCoulson The 3M™ Novec™ 8200 Engineered Fluid describes it as part of the 3M Carrier & Cleaning Solvents range. It seems odd to soak a server in a cleaning solvent to dissipate heat, rather one of the 3M Heat Transfer Fluids.

Look up Marco Reps on YouTube. He has thought a great deal about this sort of thing. Probably a temperature controlled and insulated enclosure with appropriate thermal mass will solve this problem without creating more problems.
